# How to perform asynchronous requests in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, asynchronous, geocoding, sidekiq

I want to access [geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to get latitude and longitude for the given address, but there is a [limitation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits), so I created multiple gmail accounts to access the geocoding API with multiple API keys so that I can access the API without any **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** issue

1. How to iterate those API keys in order to get latitude and longitude with sidekiq?
2. Is there any better way to achieve the above without using sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

You could do the request accounting on your end using a variable and switch between API credentials when you exhaust its limit. Also you might want to do some caching to reduce those API calls.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If you have a big consumer based application with a lot of geocoding requests, I would recommend you to go with client-side geocoding. Google provides a [Javascript SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple). You will still have a query limit but you move this to your clients. So every client will have it's own limit. So you will unlikely exceed this limit. Big sites like [Foursquare](http://foursquare.com) do this also.

If you want to be sure that the coordinates are really the coordinates of the address you have to make the calls server-side. This is in a consumer based app not very advisable. You will have to [pay Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) for more queries. This isn't very scaleable. Except if you build a enterprise application with lot less users.

However I wouldn't recommend you to try to outsmart Google by creating different accounts. Google knows these tricks and will disable your accounts. If this happens, your app won't be able to geocode anymore. And then - Boom!! `500 Internal server error`.

I hope this helps!

Happy coding :)